# Common backend Grails application

Tags: grails, module

I have a Grails Application AppA. And I am planning to create a new Grails Application AppB, wherein AppB practically uses the same services and models of AppA.

How should I approach that?

1. Extract a Grails Application AppC which would have the common services and expose that service as a remote/web/rest service?
2. Extract a Groovy project ModC that will be a jar containing the common services and models and have AppA & AppB depend on ModC?
3. Just git clone and cherry-pick every now & then?
4. Other suggestions?

Note that AppA have some lazy-loaded relationship invocations (i.e. `entity1.entity2.entity3.propName`) & GORM invocations (i.e. `Entity1.get(1L)`) from the presentation layer (controllers & views) as well. Although I can probably push some of them back to the services, I'm concerned about the refactoring effort to have the relationship invocations from the view remain intact (i.e. I would need to eager loaded some associations, or create Data Transfer Objects)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Grails way to share common functionalities, utilities and whatnot is to make a plugin that encapsulates those and install it to both projects.

A plugin can contain anything you can put in a regular Grails app -- i.e. Models, Service, Views, Controllers, config files, resources under web-app etc.

You can then either release it to an internal svn repository or just use it with `package-plugin`

**Edit:**

One way to do it while you are constantly updating the code is to have it as an inline plugin. So remove the plugin from your application.properties and add:

```
grails.plugin.location."name-of-plugin" = "/path/to/plugin/dir" // or "../plugin/"
```

This removes the necessity of reinstalling the plugin all the time. But this is for development time only.

Comment: That's what I went for, but I'm still having some problems. For example, it's cumbersome to modify the core and have it reflected to one AppA or AppB (that is, I have to reinstall the plugin again on those two projects). Not to mention that the reinstall would require me to indicate the location of the packaged plugin. I'm looking something more like a maven approach wherein you just `mvn clean install` it and other projects within the same machine (and user) would see the changes automatically. Do you know of any such means?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the option of separating your models and services (the ones used by both apps) into a plugin. I think that is the prefered way at least from what I have been following within the community.

You can take a look at [this link](http://www.nslms.com/2010/03/10/modularizing-your-grails-application-domain-classes/). It is not exactly equivalent to your case, but should give you a good idea for the plugin approach.

Answer (score 1):

I had this situation on a previous project and we used a plugin project to hold our common functionality and it worked really well.  I don't think a jar file would work well since as far as I know you wouldn't be able to take advantage of things like auto-wiring dependency injection of services, the domain/GORM/dynamic finders on domain objects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would put the functionality into a separate jar and use it in the two applications (so your suggestion no 2). I wouldn't make a new application (suggestion 1) because you just need some services not a whole web application, and I wouldn't do suggestion 3 because the services wouldn't be as reusable as with suggestion 2.